# Execute trigger after insert

Tags: mysql

I would like to execute a script (over linux) after a insert appears on a table.

What's the correct form to do it? I have this but can't run.
If I execute from mysql shell `/scripts/script1.sh` it's run correctly

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER telegram
AFTER INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
\! /scripts/script1.sh
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173646

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951746/execute-shell-commands-from-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: is it necesary to use lib_mysqludf_sys instead "\!" ?