# Call a C# function from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, dbconnect

Is it possible to call a C# function from MySQL ?

For instance, if a table changed, I'd like to call a C# function, instead of having C# constantly polling MySQL to check if a change occurred.

Comment: No, this is impossible by default.

Comment: What does the C# function do on change occurred in the database?

Comment: @Hkachhia update front-end display by using a SELECT.

Comment: You could try to use a store procedure instead. that might just work. But C# in SQL, NOPE! not yet. maybe someone is working on that project but not released. :)

Comment: Why don't use MQTT? with publish and subscribe method which decrease your polling from the frontend side.

Comment: There is SqlDependency for SQL Server, I think there should be something similar for MYSQL also

Comment: @viveknuna There isn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057725/how-to-push-mysql-database-data-to-a-mvc-net-web-application

Comment: @BradleyGrainger thank you for the information

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call a c# method from MySQL.

You'll need to re-architect your software with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible

You can execute an external process from inside MySql, see for example: [Execute shell commands from MySQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951746/execute-shell-commands-from-mysql-stored-procedure)

That process could then initiate a callback to the originating c# client, for example over a network socket.

But just because something is possible, does not mean it is a good idea!